# Install4j silent updater process hangs in case of incorrect proxy settings

Tags: install4j

The install4j silent update check process seems to hang in case Windows is configured with a "proxy script" that no longer exist. For example: when it is set to http://127.0.0.1:50000/proxy.pac, IE gives a "connection refused error", but install4j will wait indefintely while attempting to download the script.

This also prevents our own application from starting, because it is configured to start after the silent update check.

The installer and updater was created in Install4j 6.1.2. I don't see anything in the change log of 6.1.3 that would fix this issue. Can you have a look or provide us with a work around?

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000001f7f000 nid=0x1440 runnable [0x000000000028c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
                at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
                at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
                - locked <0x00000000d7c99bd0> (a java.io.BufferedOutputStream)
                at java.io.PrintStream.write(Unknown Source)
                - locked <0x00000000d7c99bb0> (a java.io.PrintStream)
                at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
                - locked <0x00000000d7c99cf8> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
                at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.PrintStream.write(Unknown Source)
                - locked <0x00000000d7c99bb0> (a java.io.PrintStream)
                at java.io.PrintStream.print(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)
                - locked <0x00000000d7c99bb0> (a java.io.PrintStream)
                at java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream.println(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Unknown Source)
                - locked <0x00000000d7c99bb0> (a java.io.PrintStream)
                at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.ProxyConfigException.<init>(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.AbstractAutoProxyHandler.getJSFileFromURL(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.AbstractAutoProxyHandler.retrieveContentOfPACFile(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.AbstractAutoProxyHandler.contructLegacyPACScript_16(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.AbstractAutoProxyHandler.init(Unknown Source)
                at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.DeployProxyHelper.getProxyHostInfoWindows(DeployProxyHelper.java:70)
                at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.ProxyHelper.getProxyHostInfoUnguarded(ProxyHelper.java:37)
                at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.ProxyHelper.access$000(ProxyHelper.java:13)
                at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.ProxyHelper$1.fetchValue(ProxyHelper.java:25)
                at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.ProxyHelper$1.fetchValue(ProxyHelper.java:22)
                at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.actions.FetchObjectAction.execute(FetchObjectAction.java:14)
                at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is in JRE classes, so we cannot fix that directly. The only option is to pass the VM parameter

```
-Dinstall4j.noProxyAutoDetect=true
```

to the installer so proxy auto-detection is switched off.